# Is it possible to insert record with PUT/PATCH http method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, put, http-method

I want to insert record with PUT/PATCH method in database. I don't want to use POST Method. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can create record even with GET. It's all possible. Recommended? Probably not.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Tunmee can you please explain me in detail, how it is possible?

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh Can you please explain,. how?

Comment: Just like a POST request, when you send a PUT or PATCH request to your server, you can send along the record you want to insert into the database in the request body. The record would be available to you on the server and you can do whatever you want with it. Take a look at this [controller](https://github.com/IAMOTZ/ievents/blob/39b497e61664a900bc0787767a7005c3b439c2b0/server/controllers/events/events.js#L110), it’s responding to a PUT request, even though I’m not inserting but instead updating a record, I could have done it the other way around.